# Difference between Iterator and reverse iterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, comparison, stable-sort

what is difference between the following two code snippets.

```
vector<int> a;
// initialization code
sort( a.rbegin(), a.rend() );
```

and

```
vector<int> a;
// same initialization as above
sort(a.begin(), a.end(), comp);
```

where comp is a boolean function given below

```
bool comp( int i, int j)
{
    return i>j;
}
```

To illustrate, the following code gives [WA](http://ideone.com/cpYRbH) while this code gives [AC](http://ideone.com/l0StTQ) for SPOJ problem [XMAX](http://www.spoj.com/problems/XMAX/).
The only difference between [AC](http://ideone.com/l0StTQ) and [WA](http://ideone.com/cpYRbH) is the version of sort() used.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the output of the sorting directly?

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: @Philipp When I tried both sorting versions gave the same output but I am confused why one version gives AC while other gives WA on SPOJ

Comment: @moderators why is there no tag for reverse-iterators??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two function calls do **NOT** give the same answer because [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is **not a stable algorithm**, i.e. it does not keep identical elements in their relative ordenings. Below an example where elements of `std::pair<int, int>` are sorted on their first element. Sorting and sorting in reverse order with the reversed comparison function does not yield identical sequences. Doing the same with [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) does yield identical results.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    typedef std::pair<int, int> Element;
    std::vector<Element> v;

    v.push_back( Element(1,1) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,1) );
    v.push_back( Element(1,2) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,2) );
    v.push_back( Element(1,3) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,3) );
    v.push_back( Element(1,4) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,4) );
    v.push_back( Element(1,5) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,5) );
    v.push_back( Element(1,6) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,6) );
    v.push_back( Element(1,16) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,16) );
    v.push_back( Element(1,22) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,22) );
    v.push_back( Element(1,33) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,33) );
    v.push_back( Element(1,44) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,44) );
    v.push_back( Element(1,55) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,55) );
    v.push_back( Element(1,66) );
    v.push_back( Element(-1,66) );

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << "(" << it->first << "," << it->second << ")" << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    auto w1 = v;
    std::sort(w1.begin(), w1.end(), [](Element const& e1, Element const& e2){ 
       return e1.first < e2. first;
    });
    auto w2 = v;
    std::sort(w2.rbegin(), w2.rend(), [](Element const& e1, Element const& e2) {
       return e1.first > e2.first;
    });
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::equal(w1.begin(), w1.end(), w2.begin()) << "\n";

    auto w3 = v;
    std::stable_sort(w3.begin(), w3.end(), [](Element const& e1, Element const& e2){ 
       return e1.first < e2. first;
    });
    auto w4 = v;
    std::stable_sort(w4.rbegin(), w4.rend(), [](Element const& e1, Element const& e2) {
       return e1.first > e2.first;
    });
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::equal(w3.begin(), w3.end(), w4.begin()) << "\n";

}
```

Output on [LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2vqzo0%2425)

Answer (score 3):

Reverse iterators simple iterate in the reverse direction of normal iterators.

So, both snippets will sort everything inside the range [first, last] both in ascending order.
The difference is in the first it will use the < operator for comparison and in the second your given function.

In detail the first actually is sorting in non-ascending order but since you also reverse tho comparison it gets reversed again, which neutralizes the effect.

NOTE: Elements that would compare equal to each other are not guaranteed to keep their original relative order.

USEFUL REFERENCES: [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), [`std::vector::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin), [`std::vector::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end),
[`std::vector::rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin),
[`std::vector::rend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend)

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, a reverse iterator visits a collection in reverse order.  If you ask the STL `sort()` algorithm to sort the range from `a.begin()` to `a.end()`, it places the resulting values in... the range from `a.begin()` to `a.end()`, in the order defined by those iterators.

So what happens if you ask it to sort the range from `a.rbegin()` to `a.rend()`?  It puts the results in...  the range from `a.rbegin()` to `a.rend()`, in the order defined by *those* iterators.

Answer (score 1):

An iterator runs from first to last, a reverse iterator runs from last to first. So `sort(a.begin(), a.end())` puts the elements in the range [first, last) in order; `sort(a.rbegin(), a.rend())` puts the elements in the range [last, first) in order, producing the opposite order from the first version.

Answer (score 0):

`rbegin` gives you an iterator that points to the end of your list and will move backward as you ask for it to move forward. Similarly,  `rend` gives you an iterator to the beginning of your list.

```
sort(a.begin(), a.end(), comp);
```

The third parameter here is used to define your own sort order. If you don't specify one then the default of that object will be used.

Answer (score 0):

They both accomplish the same thing. In the first version, you reverse the order of the iterators to get a high-to-low sort. In the second version you reverse the sense of the comparison, also getting a high-to-low sort.

Comment: sorting pairs on their first element does not give identical results, for that you need `stable_sort`

Comment: @rhalbersma, for the question as written it does not matter, as the order of identical `int`s is irrelevant. I admit I didn't link through to the examples, which evidently are more complex.